# Add two numbers up to one constant

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a constant number X. I also have two numbers that add up to it. How can I make it so that if I change one number, the other number automatically changes so that it still adds up to X.

I have tried to take subtract the one number from X and add it to the other number, but instead I got two numbers in the thousands.

Comment: Have you tried using the =SUM() formula?

Comment: I have tried using the =SUM() formula, but if I changed one number it would change the total. The total is supposed to stay a constant. Is there some function that keeps the total constant then?

Comment: So you want to keep the initial value constant and ignore any depending variable changes?

Comment: Yes. If one variable changes, the other should as well so that it still adds up to the initial value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your constant value is 10, you can set this in a cell and make all your other calculations based on it.

For example, you can have cell `C2` containing your constant, in this example, 10

Then in `C4` you can have the number which you change, and the value of `C5` will be equal to the value of the constant minus the value in `C4`.

You can then finally do your sum wherever you want, adding up the values of `C4` and `C5`.

Here's an example Spreadsheet:

---

#### Untitiled spreadsheet ☆

`File Edit View Insert Format Data Tools Extensions Help` <sub>Last edit was 2 minutes ago</sub>

`↶` `↷`  `⮷` | `100%⯆` | `$` `%` `.0` `.00` `123⯆` | `Default(Ro... ⯆` | `10 ⯆` | **`B`** | *`I`* | <strike>S</strike> | A |⯐|☰

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **2** |  | Contsant: | 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **3** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **4** |  | Number 1: | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **5** |  | Number 2: | =(C2 - C4) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **6** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **7** |  | Sum: | =(C4 + C5) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **8** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |